# Phaser Box2d - Lock drag in one direction

Tags: javascript, box2d, game-physics, drag, phaser-framework

I am working on [Phaser's Box2d](http://phaser.io/shop/plugins/box2d) plugin to build a game. In the game, objects can be dragged around with mouse. But I want to fix the drag direction i.e. object should move only horizontal or vertical direction.

I have checked official examples and docs. Couldn't find anything which serves the purpose.

[This example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/motion-lock-horizontal) shows the motion direction lock using `sprite.input.allowVerticalDrag = false`, but it is doesn't work with Box2d's drag.

I am following [this example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/box2d/mouse-drag) to enable the drag. I have tried setting `sprite.body.y` to a fix value like 300 in both `mouseDragMove` and `update` functions, so that it does move in `y` direction. But results are not smooth. It still shakes a little bit in that direction.

What can I do implement this? Am I missing any built-in option of the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution for it. What I did is to override the sprite position, in a particular axis, in `mousePointer` parameter that is passed to `mouseDragMove` handler of the framework.

Here is how it works -

```
var isDragging = false,
activeSpriteX=0,
activeSpriteY=0;

function mouseDragStart(e) {
    isDragging = true;

    //get the clicked sprite
    var currentSprite = game.physics.box2d.getBodiesAtPoint(e.x, e.y);

    //save the position of clicked sprite
    if (currentSprite.length > 0) {
        activeSpriteX = game.input.mousePointer.x;
        activeSpriteY = game.input.mousePointer.y;
    }
    game.physics.box2d.mouseDragStart(game.input.mousePointer);
}

function mouseDragMove() {
    mousePointer = game.input.mousePointer;

    //if sprite is being dragged
    if (isDragging) {
        //HERE IS THE WHOLE TRICK - 
        //just override the vertical position of `mousePointer` to sprite's initial position, when it was clicked
        //To fix the sprite in horizontal direction, just override the `x`
        mousePointer.y = activeCarY;
    }

    game.physics.box2d.mouseDragMove(mousePointer);
}

function mouseDragEnd(e) {
    game.physics.box2d.mouseDragEnd();
    isDragging = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on a game we were making and although our game doesn't use physics, what we made may be useful to you. The whole idea is to use tweens to set an object's position while dragging it (as opposed to setting its position directly) - this way you can run your checks and set your constrains manually while the tween is executing and if your input is where your object shouldn't be, you simply do not perform a tween to that position.

Comment: Thanks @Kamen for the answer. Tween doesn't seem to work when physics is enabled. I was able to figure out another solution.